# What causes "unassigned local variable" in Razor code?

Tags: c#, razor, syntax-error

I am having a little bit of an issue with some Razor C# code syntax.

I have a form which has it's action as "website.cshtml". website.cshtml should take all of the data passed in, and print it out in

tags.

Here is what I have :

```
@{
    string names = Request.Form["name"];
    string [] arrOfnames;                    // string array to hold names
    if (names != null) {                     // if the name isn't null, split into the array
        arrOfNames = names.Split(',');
    }
     foreach(string name in names)
            {
            <p>name</p>
            }

}
```

This results in the error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'arrOfNames'.

What have I done incorrectly here and how can I fix it?

Comment: your sample and error have nothing in common... Are you sure you pasted correct code/error?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My mistake, wrong error as you said!

Comment: The code as posted does not use `arrOfNames` at all, are you sure the code as it stands now is correct, and does indeed produce that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That C# compiler error results when there *is a chance* that a local variable is read from *before* it has been assigned to. (I am assuming the code is *really* `for (var name in arrOfNames)` - hint! - or `arrOfNames` is accessed later.)

It (`arrOfNames`) must be assigned on *all possible code paths* (as determined by compiler).

What if `names == null`? What would `arrOfNames` be then? C# ensures that you are *explicit* about this.

One method is to ensure a value is assigned in the "alternate path":

```
string[] arrOfnames; 
if (names != null) {
    arrOfNames = names.Split(','); // assigned here
} else {
    arrOfNames = new string[0];    // -or- here
}
```

but

```
string[] arrOfnames = null; // assign default. see below.
if (names != null) {
    arrOfNames = names.Split(',');
}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> arrOfNames = names != null
  ? names.Split(',')
  : null; // "alternate path", but single expression. see below.
```

or

```
var arrOfNames = (names ?? "").Split(',');
```

would also work.

I would recommend having an "empty collection" vs. `null`, as empty enumerable object can still be iterated over, as happens in the next few lines. On the other hand, perhaps it *should* die a ugly horrid death...

Also, consider using the interface `IEnumerable<string>` as it is often more accommodating to code changes. (Especially when used as part of a method signature.)

Happy coding.